# Attempting to dynamically create a label using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to dynamically create a `label` which gets its text through AJAX. After creating that label I am going to append in the overlay I have created. I have created an overlay but the label value doesn't appear on my overlay

This is my code. Kindly help me and tell me what am I doing wrong here.

```
var overlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"></div>');
$.ajax({
    url: "getstartingtime.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        NameOfDays: NameOfDays
    },
    success: function(data){
        var start = jQuery('<label class="timing">' + data + '</label>');
        start.appendTo(overlay);
    }
});
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
```

now when i inspected the element in my javascript the label was there
but its not showing the value it fetched in the overlay...

```
   <label class="timing">09:00:00</label>
   is there when i inspected the element
```

Comment: @palaѕн  <label class="timing">09:00:00</label> its there when i inspected the element in my chrome my no label appears on my page

Comment: What do you mean by "_its not showing the value it fetched in the overlay_"? Maybe try to explain the issue like what is fetched and what is shown instead. Only the time is the issue or something else.

Comment: @palaѕн the code is workng fine i wanted to fetch the time frm my getstartingtime.php through ajax and it worked like a charm ok the label is there the value of label which is the time 09:00:00 is there...the issue is its not on my page the label tag ion my page is blank

Comment: @palaѕн i have found the issue thankx for your concern

Answer (score 0):

I think your data variable is undefied, 
 `var start=jQuery('<label class="timing">'+data+'</label>');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
 success: function(){
        var start = $('#overlay').append('<label class="timing">' + data + '</label>');

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using appending the label in overlay in ajax success method. And you are appending the overlay outside the ajax call.

Try doing something like this. It will make sure that your overlay and label are added to DOM at the same time.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "getstartingtime.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        NameOfDays: NameOfDays
    },
    success: function(data){

        var start = jQuery('<label class="timing">' + data + '</label>');
        var overlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"></div>');
        overlay.append(start);
        $(docment.body).append(overlay);
    }
});
```